# Need help on understanding different IF statements

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

Why doesn't this work?

```
dictionary.ContainsKey(input) ? int value = dictionary[input] : "Not Found";
```

And why the following does?

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(input)) { int values = dictionary[input]; }
```

Comment: is that one for C#? Can you tag your programming language?

Comment: Yes it is, this is my first question ever in SOF.  I just made the condition = True and it corrected it a little, but i think the problem is in the First and second expression data type conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be:

```
int value = dictionary.ContainsKey(input) ? dictionary[input] : int.MaxValue;
```

But I think this would better match:

```
int value;

if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(input, out value))
{
    _Log.Message("Not found");
    return;
}

// Further process value...
```

Comment: Thank you, I am ok with the first one, I knew there is an answer for it somehow. I just wanted to challenge my self in the Conditional Operator.

Comment: @Bouzid: Right below your question (but before the first comment) are some links (share, edit, close, delete, etc). Simply select the desired one.

Answer (score 1):

The first code block is what's commonly called an "inline if" and is meant to be used with expressions, not code blocks.

As Scott mentions in the comments, in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) it's referred to as a "conditional operator".

You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Comment: Just to be pedantic it is not called a "inline if" it is the "[conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)"

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'string'  !! here is the error

Comment: This answer does nothing to answer the actual question being asked, which is why he's getting the error that he's getting.

Comment: @Servy Original question was "why doesn't this work", in which OP tried to set an int value inside what should be a string expression. So yes, this *does* answer the question.

Comment: @Crono Telling him the name of the operator does *not* explain why it doesn't work.  It just tells him the name of the operator.

Comment: @Servy *and is meant to be used with expressions, not code blocks*

Comment: That's both using incorrect terminology, and is woefully incomplete.

Comment: @Servy In programming *code blocks* is a very common way of describing whatever comes within a pair of braces, and *expressions* is the exact same term used in MSDN's documentation on ? operator. If you only care to be splitting hairs I'd suggest that you do so in comments rather than downvoting an answer. The fact that it doesn't go into elaborating what are brackets and statements doesn't make it any less a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is erroring because declaring and initializing a new local variable is a *statement*, not an *expression.  The conditional operator's second and third operands need to be expressions, not statements.

In your second code snippet you have an `if` followed by braces.  Those braces need to contain 0 to N *statements*, not expressions.  Declaring a local variable is simply valid in that context, and not the first.  Of course its worth nothing that while its syntactically valid in the second case, you're declaring a variable that can never be read, which will result in a warning because it is rather pointless.